# calling batch.dispose() gives the fatal signal 11(SIGSEGV) while trying to switch screen

Tags: android, libgdx, segmentation-fault

```js
public class Picasso extends Game {

 public static final String TAG = "debug";

 private Texture blackBar;
 private Texture blackPlayer, redPlayer,greenPlayer, redBar, greenBar;
 private Sound dropSound;
 private Music rainMusic;
 public SpriteBatch batch;
 private OrthographicCamera camera;
 private Rectangle bucket;
 private Array<Rectangle> blackPlayerList,greenPlayerList,redPlayerList;
 private long lastBlackTime,lastRedTime,lastGreenTime;
 private boolean isBlack,isRed,isGreen;

 @Override
 public void create() {
  Gdx.app.setLogLevel(Application.LOG_DEBUG);
  // load the images for the droplet and the bucket, 64x64 pixels each
  batch = new SpriteBatch();
  isBlack = true;
  isGreen = false;
  isRed = false;
  blackBar = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("bar.png"));
  blackPlayer = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("player.png"));
  redBar = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("redBar.png"));
  greenBar = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("greenBar.png"));
  greenPlayer = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("greenPlayer.png"));
  redPlayer = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("redPlayer.png"));

  // create the camera and the SpriteBatch
  camera = new OrthographicCamera();
  camera.setToOrtho(false, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());


  // create a Rectangle to logically represent the bucket
  bucket = new Rectangle();
  bucket.x = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 - 64 / 2; // center the bucket horizontally
  bucket.y = 20; // bottom left corner of the bucket is 20 pixels above the bottom screen edge
  bucket.width = 6;
  bucket.height = 6;

  // create the blackPlayerList array and spawn the first bar
  blackPlayerList = new Array<Rectangle>();
  redPlayerList = new Array<Rectangle>();
  greenPlayerList = new Array<Rectangle>();
  spawnbar(0);
  spawnRed(150);
  spawnGreen(300);
 }

 private void spawnbar(int gap) {
  Rectangle bar = new Rectangle();
  bar.x = MathUtils.random(0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth()-400);
  bar.y = Gdx.graphics.getHeight()+gap;
  bar.width = 64;
  bar.height = 64;
  blackPlayerList.add(bar);
  lastBlackTime = TimeUtils.millis();
 }

 private void spawnGreen(int gap) {
  Rectangle bar = new Rectangle();
  bar.x = MathUtils.random(0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth()-400);
  bar.y = Gdx.graphics.getHeight()+gap;
  bar.width = 64;
  bar.height = 64;
  greenPlayerList.add(bar);
  lastGreenTime = TimeUtils.millis();
 }

 private void spawnRed(int gap) {
  Rectangle bar = new Rectangle();
  bar.x = MathUtils.random(0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth()-400);
  bar.y = Gdx.graphics.getHeight()+gap;
  bar.width = 64;
  bar.height = 64;
  redPlayerList.add(bar);
  lastRedTime = TimeUtils.millis();
 }

 @Override
 public void render() {
  Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
  Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  super.render();
  dispose();
  setScreen(new GameOver(Picasso.this));

  camera.update();

  batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

  Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputAdapter(){
   @Override
   public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    if(isBlack){
     isRed = true;
     isBlack = false;
     isGreen = false;
    } else if(isRed){
     isGreen = true;
     isRed = false;
     isBlack = false;
    } else {
     isBlack = true;
     isRed = false;
     isGreen = false;
    }
    return super.touchDown(screenX, screenY, pointer, button);
   }
  });

  // begin a new batch and draw the bucket and
  // all drops
  batch.begin();
  batch.draw(blackPlayer, bucket.x, bucket.y,50,50);
  for(Rectangle bar: blackPlayerList) {
   batch.draw(blackBar, bar.x, bar.y,400,500);
  }
  for(Rectangle bar: redPlayerList) {
   batch.draw(redBar, bar.x, bar.y,400,500);
  }
  for(Rectangle bar: greenPlayerList) {
   batch.draw(greenBar, bar.x, bar.y,400,500);
  }
  if(isBlack){
   batch.draw(blackPlayer, bucket.x, bucket.y,50,50);
  }else if(isGreen){
   batch.draw(greenPlayer, bucket.x, bucket.y,50,50);
  } else{
   batch.draw(redPlayer, bucket.x, bucket.y,50,50);
  }
  batch.end();

  if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT)) bucket.x -= 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
  if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT)) bucket.x += 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

  // make sure the bucket stays within the screen bounds
//  if(bucket.x < 0) bucket.x = 0;
//  if(bucket.x > 800 - 64) bucket.x = 800 - 64;
  int rand1=MathUtils.random(1,3);
  int rand2=MathUtils.random(1,3);
  int rand3=MathUtils.random(1,3);
  // check if we need to create a new bar
  if(rand1 == 1){
   if(TimeUtils.millis() - lastBlackTime > 2500) spawnbar(0);
   if(TimeUtils.millis() - lastRedTime > 2500) spawnRed(150);
   if(TimeUtils.millis() - lastGreenTime > 2500) spawnGreen(300);
  } else if(rand1 == 2){
   if(TimeUtils.millis() - lastGreenTime > 2500) spawnGreen(0);
   if(TimeUtils.millis() - lastRedTime > 2500) spawnRed(150);
   if(TimeUtils.millis() - lastBlackTime > 2500) spawnbar(300);
  } else{
   if(TimeUtils.millis() - lastBlackTime > 2500) spawnbar(0);
   if(TimeUtils.millis() - lastGreenTime > 2500) spawnGreen(150);
   if(TimeUtils.millis() - lastRedTime > 2500) spawnRed(300);
  }

  if(rand2 == 1){
   if(TimeUtils.millis() - lastBlackTime > 2500) spawnbar(0);
   if(TimeUtils.millis() - lastGreenTime > 2500) spawnGreen(150);
   if(TimeUtils.millis() - lastRedTime > 2500) spawnRed(300);
  } else if(rand2 == 2){
   if(TimeUtils.millis() - lastBlackTime > 2500) spawnbar(0);
   if(TimeUtils.millis() - lastGreenTime > 2500) spawnGreen(150);
   if(TimeUtils.millis() - lastRedTime > 2500) spawnRed(300);
  } else{
   if(TimeUtils.millis() - lastBlackTime > 2500) spawnbar(0);
   if(TimeUtils.millis() - lastRedTime > 2500) spawnRed(150);
   if(TimeUtils.millis() - lastGreenTime > 2500) spawnGreen(300);
  }

  if(rand3 == 1){
   if(TimeUtils.millis() - lastGreenTime > 2500) spawnGreen(0);
   if(TimeUtils.millis() - lastBlackTime > 2500) spawnbar(150);
   if(TimeUtils.millis() - lastRedTime > 2500) spawnRed(300);
  } else if(rand3 == 2){
   if(TimeUtils.millis() - lastBlackTime > 2500) spawnbar(0);
   if(TimeUtils.millis() - lastRedTime > 2500) spawnRed(150);
   if(TimeUtils.millis() - lastGreenTime > 2500) spawnGreen(300);
  } else{
   if(TimeUtils.millis() - lastGreenTime > 2500) spawnGreen(0);
   if(TimeUtils.millis() - lastBlackTime > 2500) spawnbar(150);
   if(TimeUtils.millis() - lastGreenTime > 2500) spawnGreen(300);
  }

  Iterator<Rectangle> iter = blackPlayerList.iterator();
  while(iter.hasNext()) {
   Rectangle bar = iter.next();
   bar.y -= 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
   if(bar.y + 210 < 0) iter.remove();
  }

  Iterator<Rectangle> iter2 = redPlayerList.iterator();
  while(iter2.hasNext()) {
   Rectangle bar = iter2.next();
   bar.y -= 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
   if(bar.y + 210 < 0) iter2.remove();
  }

  Iterator<Rectangle> iter3 = greenPlayerList.iterator();
  while(iter3.hasNext()) {
   Rectangle bar = iter3.next();
   bar.y -= 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
   if(bar.y + 210 < 0) iter3.remove();
  }
 }

 @Override
 public void dispose() {
  // dispose of all the native resources
  blackBar.dispose();
  greenBar.dispose();
  redBar.dispose();

  blackPlayer.dispose();
  redPlayer.dispose();
  greenPlayer.dispose();

  dropSound.dispose();
  rainMusic.dispose();
  batch.dispose();
 }
}
```

Above is my code, i am trying to move to another screen in the beginning of render method just to try to switch the screen as i would need to call this later in render method but it is giving me the fatal signal 11 when i run the app and application stops and i have realized that the problem is being caused by the batch.dispose() in dispose().

If i remove the batch.dispose() code then the application runs but what happens is that both the screen runs simultaneously i.e. he current screen does not go away and the another screen also comes into play, thereby both displaying its own content.

Any idea , how do i officially switch my screen?

Answer (score 1):

`Game` is Application origin class.

`dispose()` of Game should be called when you're exiting your game. Doesn't matter on which Screen you are`render()` method of Game always called .

So try in this way :

Create another Screen(let's assume PlayScreen) like your GameOver Screen and put your render method code in render method of that Screen and most of required stuff of Picasso class.

From create method of your Picasso set `PlayScreen` by `setScreen(new PlayScreen())` method of your Game class.

Comment: What is the point of all this? You are just making me try with a new class for nothing?

Comment: I am just saying you're doing your stuff in wrong way, because render method of Game is always called by engine and so you are using batch after disposing them.

Comment: What if i write the setScreen method at the last of the render method? Will it work then?

Comment: no, what you think after setting screen, `render()` method of `Screen` called instead of Game's `render()` method. No you're wrong. Screen's render() method called by `super.render()` from Game's `render()` method.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need help with understanding what the methods do and when they are called. `create()` is called once when your Application is starting. This is essentially the initialization method. You would load your resources and objects here and set the initial state of your activity. Here is where a call to `setScreen(screen)` should go, to set the screen that will be displayed to your user in the beginning.
The `render()` method is called every frame (so typically 60 times per second). Here is where you update your objects and draw everything. But because you are using the Game class, specific screens should be implemented in their own class and in the Game class the `render()` method just clears the screen and calls `super.render()`.
The `dispose()` method disposes of the resources. This should only be called once your game is closed to free resources.